# RESTful API design pattern while creating API with php

Tags: php, web-services, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, restful-architecture

I am developing RESTful with php. Currently I have started coding with MVC design pattern. In which the view files are acting as an interface. An interface which isn't showing any graphical UI but it has all the request handling logic.

Now, my question is the way I am coding is correct or there is a better way to create RESTful api in php?

---

My inspiration is based on JavaEE application model. In which we have Entity classes as model, Java beans as controllers and Remote Interface is the the list of method which gets called from client (kind of a view).

---

Am I on right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example for building a RESTful API in a PHP based MVC framework can be found at http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/.

This example extends a class in Zend Framework called the Zend_Rest_Controller which simplifies this process. You can have a look at the [source code](http://framework.zend.com/download) to see how they do it and if it gives you an ideas on how to make your own implementation.

To answer your question though, you should have controllers acting as the interface. So if you send a POST request to myapp.com/comment (where comment is the controller), it knows you are trying to add a new comment. If you send a GET request to the same URL, it knows you want all of the comments, and if you send a GET request to myapp.com/comment/4 it knows you want to get the comment with ID 4. Your views should have nothing to do with the internal functionality of your API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any existing RESTful PHP MVC framework, like Yii or Kohana both are very light and natively support RESTful applications.

For your existing application, MVC model states that all the requests and logic handling should be done by the Controllers not the views. Things are usually done in one of two ways here:

(1) Controller has a special method to respond to each type of requests and acts differently As seen in RubyOnRails (mainly at the end of each controller action)

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.xml  { render :xml => @events}
  format.json { render :json => @events}
end
```

(2) Controller detects the current requested format and changes that entire theme/layout to, say, a JSON theme (All layouts/views receive the same data). This is my current implementation and it goes like:

```
$format is any of [html,json,xml] (detected from url suffix)
$controller->layout = "$format";
$controller->render($viewFile, $object);
```

view file in HTML Layout

```
<div id='model>
  <h1><?=$object->title?></h1>
  <p><?=$object->description?></p>
</div>
```

View file in JSON layout

```
echo json_encode($object);
```

View file in XML layout

```
/** Loop and build XML tree */
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of webinars on API Facade Design Patterns. Hope you will find the concepts useful irrespective of the underlying technology you use to implement it. Please can find it here

http://youtu.be/n8B-K3iJ7b4

http://youtu.be/MRxTP-rQ-S8

http://youtu.be/aJBhVm4BbCI

Answer (score 0):

Apigility is a Zend Framework 2 based project designed soley for the purpose of creating REST and RPC services.

https://apigility.org/

Out of the box you're given an easy way to get started with MySQL and OAuth2 for authentication.